# Key Commands must all have a Title, Key and Selector

Tags: ios, swift, beta

I am receiving and error when trying to build, Xcode 8.0 Beta 4, and when I'm building it says "error: Illegal Configuration: Key Commands must all have a Title, Key, and Selector. Select each row in the table to check its configuration."

It isn't on a TableView or anything, its a UIView with a Stack View inside it and some buttons, thats about it.

And this is on a Storyboard file I'm getting the error

I can't figure out what that might be?

Comment: Check the source file of the storyboard (right click -> open as -> source code). Are there any blank <keyCommand> labels?

Comment: </view>
                    <value key="contentSizeForViewInPopover" type="size" width="400" height="200"/>
                    <keyCommands>
                        <keyCommand/>
                    </keyCommands>
                    <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>

Comment: I removed 

                    <keyCommands>
                        <keyCommand/>
                    </keyCommands>

Comment: Thank you! I don't know what happened!

Comment: You're welcome! I figured that might be the problem. Something very similar happened to me last year. I'm going to create an answer in case other people with the same problem find this question

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Open your storyboard file as source code (right click -> open as -> source code). There should be a line, `<keyCommands> <keyCommand/> </keyCommands>`. Removing this should solve your problem.

This line can be caused by accidentally clicking the + button in the key commands section of the view controller's attributes inspector, although it may be caused by other factors. The extra line can cause weird things to happen in XCode, such as errors and crashes.

Answer (score 7):

To do this with the xcode interface builder:

1. Select your view controller
2. Select attributes inspector
3. Find "Key Commands" list at the bottom
4. Select the keys within the list, such as: "Enter action below"
5. Hit the minus button

This should fix the problem.

[Example Image, Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJQqC.png)

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution:

1. Open storyboard as "source Code" (right click on storyboard -> open as -> source code).
2. Delete this line: 
   `<keyCommands><keyCommand/></keyCommands>`
3. Run app.